# Box Plot of a many Pandas Dataframes

Tags: python, boxplot, seaborn

I have three dataframes containing 17 sets of data with groups A, B, and C. A shown in the following code snippet

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(17,3), columns=['A','B','C'])
data2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(17,3)+0.2, columns=['A','B','C'])
data3 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(17,3)+0.4, columns=['A','B','C'])
```

I would like to plot a box plot to compare the three groups as shown in the figure below
[image]
I am trying make the plot using [seaborn's box plot](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html) as follows

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.boxplot(data1, groupby='A','B','C')
```

but obviously this does not work. Can someone please help?

Comment: Is there a reason data is separated into three dataframes? What is the indicator that differs between the three?

Comment: @Parfait There is no reason to separate in three dataframes. I can combine in on data frame but then I would duplicate column names. There is indicator between the three. Other than that I know they are different because the data come from different locations

Comment: Location is the indicator! In `sns.boxplot`, you need that for the axes.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Consider assigning an indicator like *Location* to distinguish your three sets of data. Then concatenate all three and melt the data to retrieve one *value* column, one *Letter* categorical column, and one *Location* column, all inputs into `sns.boxplot`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

data1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(17,3), columns=['A','B','C']).assign(Location=1)
data2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(17,3)+0.2, columns=['A','B','C']).assign(Location=2)
data3 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(17,3)+0.4, columns=['A','B','C']).assign(Location=3)

cdf = pd.concat([data1, data2, data3])    
mdf = pd.melt(cdf, id_vars=['Location'], var_name=['Letter'])
print(mdf.head())

#    Location Letter     value
# 0         1      A  0.223565
# 1         1      A  0.515797
# 2         1      A  0.377588
# 3         1      A  0.687614
# 4         1      A  0.094116

ax = sns.boxplot(x="Location", y="value", hue="Letter", data=mdf)    
plt.show()
```

[image: Histogram Output]

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Thanks @Ghanima! Syntax issue was fixed with missing period. Please delete your comment as will I for future readers.