# Pyhon matplotlib - plot box plots from 2 different data frames

Tags: python, matplotlib

**Hello,
I'm trying to plot a box plot combining columns from two different data frames. Help please :)**

**This is the code:**

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy import random

#Generating the data frame
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = random.randn(5,2), columns = ['W','Y'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data = random.randn(5,2), columns = ['X','Y'])

print(df1.head())
print('\n')
print(df2.head())
```

**This is the output:**

[image]

**This is what I want to get:**

[image]

Comment: It is not very clear what kind of a box plot you want. A box plot simply groups data into quartiles. Are **W** and **X** supposed to be categories and you need a box plot of Y?

Comment: Hi Julia,
Y is the response column. W is the first group. X is the second group.

Comment: Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42004381/box-plot-of-a-many-pandas-dataframes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will give you what you desire:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.boxplot([df1['Y'], df2['Y']], positions=[1, 2])
ax.set_xticklabels(['W', 'X'])
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
```

This gave me the plot below (which I think is what you were aiming for):
[image]