# Plot 2 different dataframes in the same boxplot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, boxplot

So, I have 2 different datasets stored in X and Y.

```
x = df1['Sales']
y = df2['Sales']
```

I'm using the following code to plot them

```
plt.figure(figsize = (15,7))


plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
x.plot(kind='box')

plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
y.plot(kind='box')
```

And he plots them side by side, but I need it to plot on the same boxplot the 2 different DataFrames.

How can I do that?

Comment: second one also `plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Box Plot of a many Pandas Dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42004381/box-plot-of-a-many-pandas-dataframes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're working with pandas anyway, maybe this is the most straightforward approach:

```py
# put both series in one dataframe
df = pd.concat([df1['Sales'], df2['Sales']], axis=1)

# set column names (will be displayed as plot labels)
df.columns = ['x Sales', 'y Sales']  

# use pandas' boxplot method
df.boxplot()
```

You can still use all the usual matplotlib commands (e.g. `plt.figure(figsize = (15,7))`) to customize the plot.